# Python LatentDirichletAllocation fit problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

[Problems pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07KQS.png)

I am trying use LDA but something happening in python when I run it.Problems at LDA.fit(doc_term_matrix)

```
import numpy as np 

import pandas as pd 
import os

reviews_datasets = pd.read_csv("Reviews.csv")

reviews_datasets = reviews_datasets.head(20000)

reviews_datasets.dropna()

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

count_vect = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.8, min_df=2, stop_words='english')

doc_term_matrix = count_vect.fit_transform(reviews_datasets['Text'].values.astype('U'))

from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation

LDA = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=5, random_state=42)

LDA.fit(doc_term_matrix)
```

My error notes

```
 File "<ipython-input-50-e13fb5b0a923>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/PC/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/PC/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/PC/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    reviews_datasets = pd.read_csv("Reviews.csv")

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 435, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1154, in read
    df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 392, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 212, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 61, in arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1666, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1754, in form_blocks
    object_blocks = _simple_blockify(items_dict['ObjectBlock'], np.object_)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1800, in _simple_blockify
    values, placement = _stack_arrays(tuples, dtype)

  File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1863, in _stack_arrays
    stacked[i] = _asarray_compat(arr)
```

Comment: Please provide error in the question, the screenshot you shared is one where you are stopping the program execution while reading file. `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: Yes ı stopped because code  stops after a while.What can ı do ?

Comment: Oh sorry man , It works but ıt work after a long time .